# Custom tabs for unhandled applinks

Tags: deep-linking, applinks, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I have implemented **applinks** to handle all the url's from my domain as follows

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
     </intent-filter>
```

but i would like to open some links from the same domain in **customtabs**.I am implementing this logic to invoke those links in customtabs

```
    CustomTabsServiceConnection connection = new CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onCustomTabsServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, CustomTabsClient client) {
            client.warmup(0L);
            CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
            builder.setInstantAppsEnabled(false);
            builder.setToolbarColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.pure_white));
            builder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.pure_white));
            builder.setShowTitle(true);
            CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context,Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/unhandled"));
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {}
    };
    CustomTabsClient.bindCustomTabsService(context, "com.android.chrome", connection);
```

but those links were captured by my applink intent and it goes on in a loop.What am i missing? Any ideas or suggestions would be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the package on the Intent that launches the CustomTabs should force it to open Chrome.

```
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(
    context,Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/unhandled"));
```

Also, since Chrome is not the only browser that supports Custom Tabs, I'd recommend following the [best practices](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#bestpractices), and supporting other browsers as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @andreban that helped.